# Display elements using repeating table and filtering

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a problem with repeating table and display data using this table.

I try to display a elements from list **“Wydarzenia” (Events)** in my form design in InfoPath. I add **Client** using InfoPath form. After that I create **Wydarzenie** and choose **Client** from dropbox list. This drop list is reference type.

[image: Wydarzenia (Events list)]

This list shows all events. I try to display ony those that have ID equal to the client. 
The last column is ID (value take from library when I create new Client).
Down on the picture you can see "Identyfikator Klienta" (Client ID). How I can put to this field value of ID from library Client?

If something is not clearly just write, I'll try to explain more.

Best regards!

Comment: thank you very much, repeating table filter works for me.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understood, you have a receive/secondary data connection/source to a sharepoint list rendered as repeating table which you want to filter in an Infopath form template by some value.

So, having created and filled a list.

[image]

In IP form template I've created a drop-down list to choose titles by which to filter a repeating table

[image]

[image]

[image]

While the repeating table without filtering show all list items

[image]

For this I created a drop-down list box **TitlesToChooseFrom** getting choices the same secondary data connection to a list

[image]

For filtering in Fields pain I choose data source of repeating table (SharepointListItem_RW group) > **Manage Rules** on ribbon > New > Formatting  > **Hide this control** for value(s) of Title in repeating table (bound to a secondary data source ClientList, in my case) which "**is not not equal**" to a chosen one in drop-down list (Main data source)

[image]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! :) Thaks a lot!

Comment: Wonderful.. Have been trying to do this since last 1 week !!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also add another Data Connection (exactly the same) and filter it.

To do this you need to add a rule for drop down control when the value of this control changes.

Then you need choose action to set fields value and set a query data of this new Data Connection.

After that add another action in the same rule - query data and select this new DataConnection. Attach new data connection to the repeating table and that's all.

Nice description about this is here:
https://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/calling-web-service-from-infopath-2010-with-parameters/